# Django: Got FieldDoesNotExist error when changing field type in models

Tags: python, django, django-models, mongoengine, django-file-upload

I made a change in my `models.py`. I change the field from `FileField()` to `ImageWithThumbsField()`

```
from mongoengine import *
from gradfounder.settings import DBNAME
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField
from thumbs import ImageWithThumbsField

##########################################
# Mongoengine registration/authentication
#from mongoengine.django.auth import User
##########################################

#connect(DBNAME)
# connect(DBNAME, host='127.0.0.1', port=27017)
connect(DBNAME, host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port=27017)

class Author(Document):
    # photo = FileField()
    photo = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to="avatars")
    photoname = StringField()
```

Then I got this error

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", line 80, in
 __init__
    raise FieldDoesNotExist(msg)
FieldDoesNotExist: The field 'photo' does not exist on the document 'Author'
```

I tried to migrate and `syncdb` but got an error `DatabaseError: (1050, "Table 'profiles_profile' already exists")`

Anyone who wants to work on this together are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! I found the solution!

The error was caused by Mongoengine validation who got confused by the changed field. The solution is to disable the validation by adding this code:

```
class Author(Document):
    # photo = FileField()
    photo = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to="avatars")
    photoname = StringField()
    meta = {'strict': False}
```

Thanks to this question! [mongoengine - Ignore extra fields for schema validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495037/mongoengine-ignore-extra-fields-for-schema-validation)

Comment: Which package are you using for ImageWithThumbsField?

Comment: I use `django-thumbs`